# Docker CMD cant not read argument in node application

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

Here is my build command

```
docker build --build-arg APP_PROJ=proj1 --build-arg APP_ENV=dev -t proj1 .
```

Giving two argument,**APP_ENV** and **APP_PROJ**.And here is my Dockerfile content

```
FROM node:14.15 AS build

ARG APP_ENV
ARG APP_PROJ

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm i

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:${APP_PROJ}:${APP_ENV}

CMD [ "node", "dist/${APP_PROJ}/server/main.js" ]
```

I want to add an argument which can justify which project is building,but when I run docker image ,it returned an error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/${APP_PROJ}/server/main.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)

at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47{
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
}
```

- And I have checked my dist whether the main.js is exsist

It looks like dockerFile can't read enviroment variable **APP_PROJ**.How can I pass an argument to let docker read the correct main.js?

Appreciate help ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mixed up "ARGuments" and "ENVironments'.

This [doc](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/) is helping understanding the difference. Mainly, it is about that:

> ARG is only available during the build of a Docker image (RUN etc),
> not after the image is created and containers are started from it
> (ENTRYPOINT, CMD)

Thus, you will have to use ENV variables to set them up for your CMD to know about them....
Actually, you can set ENV from ARG at build time following this [documentation](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/) (same website). This is the common (not intuitive) way.

The alternative is hardcoding them in the Dockerfile (and you could use a "sed" command previous to your build to set up your DOckerfile according to your project)

Also : this may not work because variable substitution is not used when you use CMD as a list of arguments.  You may have to switch to raw CMD (`CMD dosomething "$myvar ${anotherVar}"`) or use the shell form of CMD (`CMD dosomething $myvar ${anotherVar}`)

Comment: You saved my day!!As you said,the origin CMD didnt recognize ENV .And I fixed it to raw. It finally works!!